# How can I declare that a constant is defined in PhpDoc (for intelephense)?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpdoc, docblocks, intelephense

### TL;DR

How can I document a constant that is defined in external code using PhpDoc/DocBlocks so that it will not show up as an undefined variable in static code analysis?

### Details:

I'm trying to write a small WordPress plugin. I have some PHP code like below.

```
defined('ABSPATH') or die('Access denied!'); // Avoid direct file request

function getPluginInfo($key) {
    require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
    $data = get_plugin_data(MY_PLUGIN_FILE, true, false);
    return $data[$key];
}
```

I'm using the VSCode plugin [vscode-intelephense](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense) (which provides a PHP language service). I have all the necessary dependencies installed, including listing "wordpress" as a stub in the VSCode settings. In general, the intelephense is working quite well and is doing a great job of showing information about my code as well as WordPress library code.

However intelephense shows an error: **"Undefined constant '...\ABSPATH' (1011)"** (where the dots are a namespace that I have omitted for brevity).

So it appears that intelephense doesn't pick up on the condition implied by the first line -- namely that if `ABSPATH` isn't defined, execution won't reach the later code that references it. (Which is perfectly fine, program flow analysis might be demanding too much). Anyway, I think I should be able to add some kind of PhpDoc (or another commented annotation) to indicate to code analyzers that the variable **is** defined. Something like this:

```
/**
 * @var string ABSPATH
 */
```

or this:

```
/**
 * @global string ABSPATH
 */
```

But neither of those cause the error to go away. (I also tried `@const` which doesn't appear to be a real tag. It didn't work either.)

Is there some way in the code I can indicate that ABSPATH is defined in external code or in an out scope? Adding a line at the top of the function like `global ABSPATH;` doesn't seem to be right either, because `ABSPATH` isn't a variable. It's a `define`-created constant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the wordpress stub that you have enabled to give you wp intellisense, you would have to create a stub file for your constants and add it to your workspace so that it can be indexed.

```php
<?php

const ABSPATH = '';
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll also mention, for anyone else interested, that local folder paths can be added to the list of stubs, so this custom stub file doesn't need to be placed in the actual workspace code. [See issue here for example](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/907)